# Show that $d_{f+g}(\alpha+\beta) \leq d_{f}(\alpha)+d_{g}(\beta)$, where $d_h(c)=\mu(\{x \in X:|h(x)|>c\}$

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, measurable-functions

I was reading Grafakos book from classical Fourier Analysis (thir edition, 2o14). Let $(X,\Omega,\mu)$ a measure space and let $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ a measurable function. First, for $\alpha>0$, he defines $d_{f}(\alpha)=\mu(\{x \in X:|f(x)|>\alpha\})$ (the *distribution function of $f$*). Then, in a proposition (the proof is an excersice), he states that for $\alpha, \beta>0$ and $f,g$ measurable functions, 
$$d_{f+g}(\alpha+\beta) \leq d_{f}(\alpha)+d_{g}(\beta).$$
I tried to prove this but i just have 
$$\{|f+g|>\alpha+\beta\} \subset \{|f|+|g|>\alpha+\beta\}.$$
I also tried to separate
$$\{|f+g|>\alpha+\beta\} \subset \{|f|>\alpha\}\cup\{|g|>\beta\},$$
but I think that this isn't true (cause maybe $f$ is small (say $|f|<\alpha$) and $g$ very large (say $|g|>\alpha+\beta$)).
So, I don't know how to prove this propiety...

Obs: From the same proposition, I also know that if $|g| \leq |f|$ $\mu-$a.e. implies $d_{g} \leq d_{f}$ (this is obvious because if $|g|>\alpha$, then $|f|>\alpha$) and that $d_{cf}(\alpha)=d_{f}(\alpha/|c|)$ for $c \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ (this follows for a chain of equalities of sets).

Comment: The property $$\{|f+g|>\alpha+\beta\} \subseteq \{|f|>\alpha\}\cup\{|g|>\beta\}$$ is quite true. To prove it, you might want to try the complement property $$\{|f|\leqslant\alpha\}\cap\{|g|\leqslant\beta\}\subseteq\{|f+g|\leqslant\alpha+\beta\}$$

Comment: thank you!, now i see it clearly: if $x$ is in the intersection, then $|f(x)| \leq \alpha$ and $|g(x)| \leq \beta$. So $|f(x)|+|g(x)| \leq \alpha +\beta$, but $|f(x)+g(x)| \leq |f(x)|+|g(x)|$ so $x$ is in the RHS.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that $f, g\ge 0$. The inclusion
$$\tag{1}
\{f+g>\alpha+ \beta \}\subset \{f>\alpha\}\cup\{g>\beta\}
$$
is true. To see this, consider the basic set theory fact that 
$$
A\subset B\cup C\quad \iff \quad B^c\cap C^c \subset A^c, 
$$
where $X^c$ denotes the complement of $X$. So (1) is true if and only if 
$$
\{f\le \alpha \}\cap \{g\le \beta\}\subset \{f+g\le \alpha+\beta\}, $$
and this is manifestly true.

Comment: I now see that this is exactly the same thing as Did's comment to the main question.